# storing lists that can be edited in a loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, enums

I want to take the strings inside of a list I have and convert them into there proper enums. The code using enum.parse works in doing this. The problem with my code is that it doesn't store dispoFilters after leaving the loop. What would be a good way around this problem?

```
// Get Disposition enum
if (model.FilterSet.Dispositions != null)
{
    List<int> dispoFilters = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < model.FilterSet.Dispositions.Count; i++)
    {
        dispoFilters.Add((int)((RespondentStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(RespondentStatus), model.FilterSet.Dispositions[i].ToString())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are correct, but you don't even have to use a for loop. Here is what you can do:

```
var dispoFilters = model.FilterSet.Dispositions.ConvertAll(item => 
    (int)((RespondentStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(RespondentStatus), item.ToString())));
```

I'm assming that `model.FilterSet.Dispositions` is a `List`; If not, you'll have to use `toList()` before `ConvertAll`.

Answer (score 8):

Your code doesn't store dispoFilters after leaving the IF statement.

Move your declaration up a bit higher.

```
List<int> dispoFilters = new List<int>();
if (model.FilterSet.Dispositions != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model.FilterSet.Dispositions.Count; i++)
    {
        dispoFilters.Add((int)((RespondentStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(RespondentStatus), model.FilterSet.Dispositions[i].ToString())));
    }
}
```

[Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is the term used to define how long, and to which parts of code, your variables are available.  By declaring the variable inside the `if` statement, you lost your scope when you exited the if.

Answer (score 5):

Thats is because you have defined `dispoFilters` inside the `if` block and it wont be available outside of it. So define it outside the `if` or to an upper **[scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx)** based on where you need it. Also note that it is not that it is not available outside the loop (as you have mentioned) it will be available outside the loop but within your `if` condition.

```
List<int> dispoFilters = new List<int>();
if (model.FilterSet.Dispositions != null)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < model.FilterSet.Dispositions.Count; i++)
     {
         dispoFilters.Add((int)((RespondentStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(RespondentStatus), model.FilterSet.Dispositions[i].ToString())));
     }
 }
```

Based on your code:

```
if (model.FilterSet.Dispositions != null)
     {
         List<int> dispoFilters = new List<int>();
         for (int i = 0; i < model.FilterSet.Dispositions.Count; i++)
         {
             dispoFilters.Add((int)((RespondentStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(RespondentStatus), model.FilterSet.Dispositions[i].ToString())));
         }
        //With in the if condition outside the loop you can still access dispoFilters 
     }
```